# Exec <Stored procedure> extremely slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, bids

I have a very large Stored Procedure that takes a single parameter `@date`. When I highlight the SQL code and hit execute, the query runs in about 25 seconds. But if I try to run the Stored Procedure in a separate window using:

```
Exec <Stored Procedure> @date = '2013-10-16'
```

The Stored Procedure takes about an hour and a half to run. Any ideas on why this might be happening? I am also trying to run this through BIDS and the Stored Procedure takes just as long to run.

Note: When I highlight the code to execute, I use

```
Declare @date as date = '2013-10-16'
```

to set the parameter.

Comment: I'd check the source tables that are being used inside the proc and see 1. how big they are and 2. indexes and fragmentation of the indexes.

Comment: Try clearing your sql execution plan.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288808/sql-server-2005-how-do-you-clear-out-a-query-execution-plan

Comment: Highlighting the code with the create/alter statement of the stored procedure, will create/save the stored procedure.

On a second window you are actually executing the procedure to bring results, if is taking to much time, maybe there is a indexing problem, or the amount of data is too much to process, use the execution plan to check where is being more slow

Comment: @Ashwin Chandran Unfortunatly I don't have the permissions to run that in my current position, I'll see if I can get someone to do it.

Comment: @Juan Garcia When i highlight the code I do not include the Create/alter part, just the code part, which actually does return a table of values that is expected from the query. Where can i find the execution plan? I've never seen it before.

Comment: There is a button in the SQL Management Studio, with two boxes in blue and one in green and a text globe, is near the Execute and Parse (Blue Check) buttons.

Comment: On the query menu, there is a button "Include Actual Execution Plan". If you mouse over the menu, you should be able to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say it runs fast if you declare the parameter variable and run the sql manually, but takes ages when you run it through BIDS I think of parameter sniffing.

Try declare a variable in your SP, then the first thing you do is assign the value of your parameter to this new local variable, then use the local variable everywhere in your SP.

For more info :http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx

Comment: Wow I never would have thought of that, this worked! Thanks so much.