# Getting wrong results whith specific "WHERE" condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

gurus.
I'm stuck with my problem and will appreciate any help or suggestion. Please check [this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQjh4.png).
I don't understand why I'm getting wrong result in bottom query. As you can see the difference with previuos query is only in "WHERE" clause, but this difference must lead to the same results since it's one-to-one join.
Important thing is that `v_last_part_info` is as a view and I changed it recently. I thought it's due to QEP cache, but i tried `OPTION (RECOMPLIE)` and even solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288808/sql-server-2005-how-do-you-clear-out-a-query-execution-plan). The result is still same.
Please, help! What am I missing?

---

P.S.: `[OBJECT_ID]` is a column name, not built-in function

---

P.P.S: ANOTHER_DB has different collation that's the reason i need `collate database_default`

---

```
select Tracking
    , SoItem 
from v_last_part_info 
where Tracking = '4170664293'

Tracking    SoItem
4170664293  20
--================================================================================--
select 
    lpi.Tracking
   , lpi.SoItem
from v_last_part_info lpi
    join ANOTHER_DB..SO_HEADER h on lpi.Tracking = h.[OBJECT_ID] collate database_default
where Tracking = '4170664293'

Tracking    SoItem
4170664293  20
--================================================================================--
select 
    lpi.Tracking
    , lpi.SoItem
from v_last_part_info lpi
    join ANOTHER_DB..SO_HEADER h on lpi.Tracking = h.[OBJECT_ID] collate database_default
where [OBJECT_ID] = '4170664293'

Tracking    SoItem
4170664293  10
```

Comment: please lay out the data in text rather than asking us to click on the link for a pic. In order for the question and answer to be useful for later searchers we need to have the tables you are joining so we can check to see what is going on. The link to a pic will die too soon for this to be useful for long.

Comment: add other column h.so item and try to add LTRIM and RTRIM but why that result is 10

Comment: Note if [OBJECT_ID] and [Tracking] are numeric types columns you don't need the quotes on the literals nor the collations.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowledge of your schemas. In particular if [v_last_part_info] is a view, if [lpi.SoItem] is a computed column and if it's values is being updated on the fly at the same time you are testing it

Comment: What is the definition of `v_last_part_info`? Can you post this? Given the indeterminate results, and the presence of `last` within the view name my guess would be that you are using `TOP` somewhere within the view, and the `ORDER BY` is either not present, or does not contain enough items to make the results of the view deterministic, thus when querying different columns different execution plans are generated and the results are different.

Comment: @ghangas, thanks for the comment, I didn't know that link will die soon. Anyway, the result is present at the code I posted (I'm sorry that's not ovviuos. Next time i'll make my post better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [GarethD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048425/garethd) I found out the reason. This happened because of `row_number()` function inside `v_last_part_info`. Accorgin to the [definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) at MSDN:

> There is no guarantee that the rows returned by a query using
> ROW_NUMBER() will be ordered exactly the same with each execution
> unless the following conditions are true.
>
> 1. Values of the partitioned column are unique.
> 2. Values of the ORDER BY are unique.
> 3. Combinations of values of the partition column and ORDER BY columns are unique.

In my case option 2 was not secured.